# What version of TensorFlow+Keras should I install for nVidia GeForce GTX 480?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\Users\pc>nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:32_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176


C:\Users\pc>nvidia-smi
Fri Nov 10 14:02:45 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 391.35                 Driver Version: 391.35                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 480    WDDM  | 00000000:03:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 44%   63C   P12    N/A /  N/A |    360MiB /  1536MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

C:\Users\pc>
```

I am running Python 3.11. So, I tried to install TensorFlow 2.0.0 and received the following error:

```
C:\Users\pc>pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 
(from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 
2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.15.0rc0, 2.15.0rc1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0
```

I need to run neural network training.

What version of TensorFlow+Keras should I install for this GPU configuration?

Comment: What version of python are you running? `pip install tensorflow` should install the latest version available to you. Its very likely you couldn't install 2.0.0 because of your python version

Comment: @0x00, I am running Python 3.11.

Comment: None. There is not and has never been support for compute capability 2.x devices in Tensorflow and CuDNN

Answer (score -1):

For your GPU configuration (CUDA 9.0, NVIDIA driver 391.35), install TensorFlow 1.14.0 and Keras 2.2.4 with:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14.0 keras==2.2.4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).